# Children’s book about a tadpole and a rude fish

Tags: identification-request

I’m looking for the name of the children’s book. It had a green cover and must have been around in the 90s/2000s. I can’t remember a huge amount about it, I but vaguely remember a rude fish saying ‘who are you?’ to the tadpole.